# How to get value of inputs onChange when they are inside map function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get value of select in React but I get empty value.

```
          <select value={predmet} onChange={(e) => setPredmet(e.target.value)}  id="post-name" name="predmet" >
    {listaPredmeta.map(({ label, value }) => (
      <option  id={value} value={value}>
        {label}
      </option >
    ))}
      </select>
```

I cant figure out why, I guess it has to do something with map function.

Additional code. Function getData() is inside main component function.

```
  const [listaPredmeta, setlistaPredmeta] =useState([]);

function getData() {

const data = {
  IdUniverziteta: parseInt(UserProfile.getUser("uni"), 10),
  IdSmera: parseInt(UserProfile.getUser("smer"), 10)
};
    const url3 = "https://localhost:44357/api/Fin/Predmet";
    axios
    .post(url3, data)
    .then((result) => {
      const predmeti= [];
      function predmetSet(item){
        const uniData2 = item.split("_");
        predmeti.push({
          label: uniData2[1],
          value: uniData2[0]
       })
      }
      const predmetData = result.data.split(";");
      predmetData.forEach(predmetSet);
      setlistaPredmeta(predmeti);
    });

}

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Comment: Could update your question and share the code of the state for `predmet` and the `listaPredmeta`

Comment: I just updated code, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so...
The problem was in the default value. The code I posted above works perfectly, but it does not have a default value by itself.
So I did something not so elegant, but it worked.

```
        const url3 = "https://localhost:44357/api/Fin/Predmet";
    axios
    .post(url3, data)
    .then((result) => {
      const predmeti= [];
      function predmetSet(item){
        const uniData2 = item.split("_");
        predmeti.push({
          label: uniData2[1],
          value: uniData2[0]
       })
      }
      const predmetData = result.data.split(";");
      predmetData.forEach(predmetSet);
      setlistaPredmeta(predmeti);
    });
    setPredmet(1); // I SET DEFAULT VALUE IN THIS LINE
```